# Angular 2 - Odd behavior with .replace() for a URL

Tags: angular, rest

I am writing an application that allows the user to search for data by selecting the type they want to search by and entering what to search in a textbox.  An option in the search type is to search the data by URLs, so the search API will look something like: `rest/search/{searchType}/{searchText}`.  If the user selects to search by URL and enters in `https://app1.my.url.com`, the API will be `rest/search/applicationURL/https://app1.my.url.com`.  Obviously that is invalid, so I am encoding the URL by using `encodeURIComponent()`, but that doesn't encode the `.`'s, so I am manually replacing them with `%2E` (the encoding for `.`).

In my GET function, I have the following code:

```
search() {
  if(searchType=='applicationURL') {
    //encode the search Text, which will be a URL
    searchText = encodeURIComponent(searchText);
    //searchText, if 'https://app1.my.url.com', will be http%3A%2F%2Fapp1.my.url.com
    searchText = searchText.replace(/\./, '%2E');
    console.log(searchText); //for testing
   }
   //call custom GET function
   this.submitService.GET('rest/search/' + searchType + '/' + searchText)
      .subscribe(data => {
         ....
      });
  }
```

This is where the strange behavior comes in.  From the console.log, I can see that the final value of `searchText` is http%3A%2F%2Fapp1%2Emy%2Eurl%2Ecom, but my GET call shows `rest/search/applicationURL/http%3A%2F%2Fapp1.my.url.com`, so it's not finishing replacing the values before it makes the call.  I thought there my be a synch issue with using `encodeURIComponent()`, so I tried manually replacing the `/`'s and `:`'s in the URL.  Even when I did that, it ignored the `.`'s being encoded when making the call, even though the final value of searchText was correct.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: My gut feeling is that you should not use arbitrary string as route part, considering switching to query parameters or put it in body.

Comment: @HarryNinh It works for every other type of search item, for regular strings or numbers, it's just that encoding the periods for URLs doesn't happen.

Comment: I'm not saying it does not work at all, it's just not designed to be used for that purpose.